# Ошибка при подключении сервера к Callback API

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, pythonanywhere

Есть простой бот на vk_api. Я хочу подключить его к Callback API в группе ВК через Flask. Использую хост Pythonanywere (создаю приложение). При запуске самого кода (через консоль) происходит ошибка RuntimeError: Working outside of request context. При попытке подключения к Callback API приложение просто возвращает стандартный текст. Как избавится от ошибки?

```py
from flask import Flask, request, json
import vk_api
import vk
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
import requests

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='токен')
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, ID_группы)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ["POST"])

def main():
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    if data['type'] == 'confirmation':
        return 'код подтверждения'
    elif data['type'] == 'message_new':
        for event in longpoll.listen():
            if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                if event.obj.text == '!Привет':
                    if event.from_user:
                        vk.messages.send(
                            user_id=event.user_id,
                            random_id=get_random_id(),
                            message='Привет'
                        )
                    elif event.from_chat:
                        return 'ok'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: ошибка в консоли]
   [image: ошибка в вк]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было всего лишь поменять версию CallBack API в настройках группы ВК на более низкую (5.80)